# How to manage a uiveri5 test which based on two applications

Tags: uiveri5

We are using uiveri5 for testing our application. Our scenario is this,
- Create a plan in first application
- Go to second application with created plan id using application navigation functionlity. 
- Make some steps there, upadte the plan
- Return to first application, maintain data in second application will be available in first application.

Issue :
When we create a plan and go to second application with new plan id, the controls of second appliation are not identified.

```
browser.wait(()=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url)=>{
    publicUrl = url;
    browser.get(url);
  });
});
```

Our code to redirect to second application
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url);

Expectation FAILED: Failed: No element found using locator:

```
by.control({"searchOpenDialogs":true,"controlType":"sap.m.Button",
"bindingPath":{"path":"/actionMenu"}})
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the redirection creates a new JS context e.g. reloads the JavaScript VM. And in this new context, you don't have the uiveri5 helper scripts that implements the synchronization and control locators (by.control()).
We have some guidelines how to implement such workflow here: https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/docs/usage/browser.md